# Wordpress widget/sidebar dividers?

Tags: php, widgets, sidebar, list, register-sidebar

I have a widget sidebar, but I'd like dividers between them. I can achieve this in CSS using boring borders, but I have a png image I'd rather use instead.

Is there a way to insert a divider after each widget item? (apart from the last one of course). I can do this in jQuery quite easily but I'd rather do it in the template file if at all possible

I'm guessing it's something for the functions file or where I register the sidebar?

Thank you

Comment: I guess I could add code after: 'after_widget' => '</li>' ? Or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: The solution for excluding the last widget you can find here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-first-and-last-css-classes-for-sidebar-widgets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'after_widget' => '',
```

As far as I know, thats the best way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You could use the :after CSS pseudo class, it's [widely supported now](http://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/) and it accepts image content.

```
.widget:after{
    content:url(img/divider.png);
}
```

But I'm afraid that you cannot treat the last widget differently here, or you will have to add a specific class to all the widgets but the last one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by modifying the css of the widget item. You can do more in CSS than the regular borders:

```
.widget{
background:url('../img/divider.png') no-repeat center bottom;
}
```

No php or unsupported CSS needed.